# Cannot find namespace 'firebase' when used with angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire, typescript-typings, angularfire2

I want to start an Angular2 Typescript project using AngularFire2.

I followed the exact instructions found here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md

But when I do a `ng serve` I get multiple errors `Cannot find namespace 'firebase`.

I've googled for hours and most "solution" don't work or are obselete/old.

However, the app launched and actually works fine but having 20 red errors all the time is annoying and makes debugging a hassle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some code to the question? It is not clear what parts are red. My direct notion is missing typings. Have you installed typings with `typings install` (and possibly restarted your IDE afterwards)?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same problem!

Comment: Nope. Firebase seems to not have updated to RC5. I will leave this for now until Angular/AngularFire2/Firebase is more mature and battle tested.

Answer (score -2):

Try declare firebase ambiently since angularfire2 imports firebase already which exposes the fireabse namespace globally:

```
declare var firebase: any;
```

Installing typings is not neccessary. I'm using:

```
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
"firebase": "^3.4.0",
```